# Where can I find the contents of signalr/hubs

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

In a typical SignalR view it includes...

```
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

I'm trying to get my head around SignalR and want to look at the javascript within this folder. But I cant find it within my project.

Also, I understand this contains javascript that is generated customised for my hub class etc. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. It's dynamically generated so that's why you can't see it in visual studio. Enable directory browsing in your web.config by adding

```
<system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

You can then navigate to `localhost/signalr/hubs` to see the file contents.

Answer (score 3):

The `/signalr/hubs` file is dynamically created by the SignalR server when the app boots up.  Since the SignalR server hangs off of the `/signalr` endpoint it then generates the `/hubs` ontop of it.

Here's how SignalR 2.0.2 generates the file at a high level:  https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/2.0.2/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/DefaultJavaScriptProxyGenerator.cs .

And here's where it determines that the request is to `/signalr/hubs` (in 2.0.2) https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/2.0.2/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/HubDispatcher.cs#L235-L253

Finally to answer your last question, it absolutely does.  This is why it's dynamically generated.  If you'd ever like to get a physical file that represents the `/signalr/hubs` endpoint you can follow the instructions here: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#manualproxy

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there any way to get content of this file via some call and insert it into page?